# Jquery data.success is not working with laravel 5.8

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am sending data through ajax to controller and return a json response, but when i am trying to perform action using response it's not working.

**Jquery code**

```
$.ajax({headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
                  type:'POST',

                  url:'/save-item',
                  data:datas,
                  success:function(data){
                    if(data.success){
                              alert("done"); 

                                }
                      },
            //error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              //console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
              error: function (data) {
                            console.log('Error:', data);
        }

        });
```

**Laravel Code**

```
public function saveItem(Request $request){

        print_r($request->input('iname'));

         $input = $request->input('iname');
        //print_r(Input::all());

        return response()->json(['success'=>true]);
    }
```

Comment: can you try removing `print_r($request->input('iname'));`?

Comment: `it's not working` -- ok, are you getting an error? Is your laravel route setup to be a POST? Please be more specific.

Comment: @Froxz Thanks i am doing this stupid mistake it's working after removing the `print_r($request->input('iname'));`

Comment: Also, @Froxz is more than likely correct. If you are outputting something before it can set the json header, it is probably throwing a headers already sent error.

Comment: @JeremyHarris no error just the content is not JSON anynmore because the output will be: `value_of_input_name{"success":true}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `print_r` before sending `response`, all info from `print_r` will be prepended to your actual response:

```js
value_of_input_name{"success":true}
```

in this case is not a valid json anymore, and `jQuery` can't read it/parse.